# Building R package "no visible global function definition for" shiny functions

Tags: r, function, package, shiny

Im trying to check my own package with

```
Rcmd.exe check dbt.ORA_1.0.tar.gz.
```

despite of adding "Depends: shiny in the Description file,

I get alot of warnings like this:

...

- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'runApp'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'fluidPage'
- dbtORA: no visibleglobal function definition for 'titlePanel'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'sidebarLayout'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'sidebarPanel'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'selectInput'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'checkboxInput'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'conditionalPanel'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'numericInput'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'actionButton'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'mainPanel'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'textOutput'
- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'uiOutput'

...

the function dbtORA is very long, the source code is like this:

```
dbtORA <-function(){
...
outputApp=runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
...
),
 server = function(input, output, session){
...
  }  
))
...
return(outputApp=NamedORAResults)}
```

I have in this context also a second question:

How do I declare functions, which are only locally defined, e.g. in

```
dbtORA <-function(){
...
matlabmin=function(...){...}
...}
```

gives the warning:

- dbtORA: no visible global function definition for 'matlabmin'

Comment: There's a couple of fixes depending on whether or not there's a way to bind the variable in the package you're using.  The universal fix is to put `dbtORA <- NULL` at the top of your script before the variable is called.  The problem is you likely that have some sort of function that is probably reading a variable from a data.frame or list and using [non standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

Comment: dbtORA is a functon not variable, which uses alot other functions and is able to start a shiny interface. I dont understand your suggestion

Comment: Did you declare the package functiontions you're using in the NAMESPACE imprts?  The solution depends on whether you manage this manually or with something like `devtools`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this? I use Rstudio with Rtools, all checks are done automatically.

Comment: Do you use roxygen2?  If not I highly recommend it (+ devtools ; which is built into alot of RStudio).  Here's more on NAMESPACES: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces but roxygen would make this management easier.

Answer (score 2):

For all of you, who have the same problem:

1. In the DESCRIPTION file you have to write

   Imports: shiny

   and not

   Depends: shiny
2. In the NAMESPACE file you have to write

   ```
   import(shiny)
   ```

No clue, why it has to be done like this only with shiny...