# How to fix `no visible global function definition` when creating a new R-package

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I try to build an R-package that uses the library `tidyverse`.

The description file looks like the following:

```
Package: myFirstPackage
Title: A initial package
Version: 0.0.1.0
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "Test",
           family = "Test",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: a description.
Imports: tidyverse
License: GPL-2
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

So I added `tidyverse` to the `Imports` section.

My R-Code looks like the following:

```
myfunction<-function(){

  x<-tibble(
    id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    name = c("Louisa", "Jonathan", "Luigi", "Rachel"),
    female = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
  )
  x %>% pull(id)
}

#' MyDemoFunction
#'
#'
#' @import tidyverse
#' @export

say_hello<-function(){
  cat("here1")
  myfunction()
}
```

Also here, I have the import.

I am working with R-Studio and as soon as I pressed Check, I get:

```
> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  myfunction: no visible global function definition for 'tibble'
  myfunction: no visible global function definition for '%>%'
  myfunction: no visible global function definition for 'pull'
  myfunction: no visible binding for global variable 'id'
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    %>% id pull tibble
```

You find the repo of the project [here](https://github.com/anewruser/r_package_project).

In [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026637/no-visible-global-function-definition-for) the problem was solved by importing function by function but I want to have complete import of the package: I simply want to use all function of tidyverse without defining each of them explicitly. In the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026630/building-r-package-no-visible-global-function-definition-for-shiny-functions) it was mentioned that the import has to be in the description which I have already!

Comment: you could create a file with globals

Comment: I added an addtional r file with the following content
 if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")  utils::globalVariables(c(".")) 
However, it doesn' t help (see https://github.com/anewruser/r_package_project/blob/master/R/globalR.R)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for a clean check. You need R 4.1.0 to use |> operator.

plainSrc.R:

```r
####This File represents a package used for Index Management

### Overall approach of this package ###
# In order to avoid a static hard coding of the index members
# we use a web-based approach based on finanzen.de from there we
# get the index members for which we offer the data.

#' @import dplyr
#'
myfunction<-function(){

  x <- dplyr::tibble(
    id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    name = c("Louisa", "Jonathan", "Luigi", "Rachel"),
    female = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
  )
  x |> dplyr::pull(one_of("id"))
}

#' MyDemoFunction
#'
#'
#' @export
#'
say_hello<-function(){
  cat("here1")
  myfunction()
}
```

and change Imports in DESCRIPTION from tidyverse to dplyr.

Comment: works, but why is tidyverse not working - it should be a super set of dplyr (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/#installation)

Comment: TL;DR tidyverse is simple wrapper to make a few library at once. This is quite tricky to understand. `tidyverse` is not targeted to be used inside other packages. It is a package which offer an easy way to library many packages at once, check the onAttach function (invoked when library(tidyverse)) - https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/blob/master/R/zzz.R. The functions e.g. from dplyr could not be accessed by :: inside tidyverse. BTW. be careful to NOT use library at .R files inside package. Sometimes we use `if (!require("package")) stop("you need x to proceed")`.